# How can I activate a button without it being pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

So I am trying to make a JButton get activated without it being actually pressed. However, I want this action to be performed only if a rectangle-jcomponent is touched by my player. How can I achieve this? Can I check if the position of my player is the same with the one I need and then maybe use a boolean to activate the button :?

Here's how I have handled a "normal" click on the button. Now I additionally want the button to be activated, if the player touches the end-goal...

```
buttonarea.goal_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cl.show(frame.getContentPane(), "Goal 1 WON");
                gamingarea.getPanel().requestFocusInWindow();                       
            }
            
        });
```

Comment: You can invoke the `doClick()` method of the button.

Comment: Yes that helped me out a lot, thank you!